# Other causes of PHP inserting escape characters besides magic_quotes_gpc

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4, eloquent

**Edit:** It has been quite rightly pointed out to me that my original approach to this question was focusing on the wrong problem. I have now restructured it to focus on the root cause rather than my specific goals. I will continue to keep the question updated with what I try.

I am building an application in Laravel 4 that is due to be deployed on a production server that is currently adding escape slashes to any string added to the database. (this isn't happening on my local development environment). I have tried investigating whether it would be possible to prevent this from happening by disabling `magic_quotes_gpc` in the PHP configuration but it was already disabled.

It would be preferable to be able to resolve the root cause of this problem. To that end any pointers as to what other configuration options could be the cause of the problem would be gratefully received. I will continue to look into this myself and keep the question up to date with what I have tried.

My original question was how I could find a way to apply `stripslashes()` at a model level so that the escape characters are at least appearing in my views. Ideally I would like this not to be necessary however I cannot rule out pursuing this as a short term remedy if it were achievable.

Comment: Personally, I would try more to find the **cause of the problem**, rather than adding lots of code to work around it. You can have an upvote regardless, good luck.

Comment: This is wrong a question to ask. You have to make sure that slashes **weren't added** rather than they were removed.

Comment: This question sounds a bit like: Oh shit where do these slashes comne from? Ah well let's check if magic quotes is enabled. *quick look* oh seems not to be. Oh I have no clue, let's not care about that, just hit in a question on stackoverflow, they always have *good* ideas for any case.

Comment: I see you rewored the question. As this is troubleshooting related, just a question back: Are you aware of the three settings outlined here: http://php.net/security.magicquotes.disabling? Also which PHP version (and perhaps configuration) is that server system using (e.g. `phpinfo()`)?

Comment: Thanks for pushing me away from the wrong approach. I've actually managed to resolve the issue myself now. Turns out `magic_quotes_gpc` was active after all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out that I was mistaken when I checked the status of `magic_quotes_gpc`. When I looked at `phpinfo()` it was flagged as still enabled while WHM's PHP Configuration Editor was displaying it as "<del>Off</del> ** DEFAULT **".

Manually setting it to Off resolved the problem

Answer (score 2):

> In lieu of being able to prevent this from happening I need to find a way to ensure that all text output has the slashes removed. My codebase is already fairly large so stripping slashes from every field manually would be highly impractical.

So don't add them in the first run. There is nothing to discuss here, find the issue on the server and clean the mess up. It might cost you a day or two (actually normally much faster), but this doesn't cost you to insert an akward fantasy layer that is interrupting inputs to an extend you don't want. It will only cost you days in the long run.

And just a nice meant reminder: Who tells you that `stripslashes()` would actually prefectly well invert the apply of the slashes that happen to happen magically and of which you so far don't know *where* it comes from?

Be fair, tell everybody you step in the dark and you now want to collect best suggestions of which you will pick the one you deem working (while still stucking in the dark). Instead get light and get sight. Otherwise you are chasing a ghost and that can fall back pretty hard on you. The haunted server slash ghost :D